# expressJS : separating route, model, making exported properties from model to route to work async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im new to js/nodejs/express, and on my own tried to structure my file in an MVC like pattern

The problem is the **console.log** (at routes.js, the most important) returns **undefined**, while the second one returns the real data, and is executed by node respectively as well, How would I return that data in an async manner from my model to the route?

**In my server.js**

```
require('./modules/pos/routes')(app);
require('./modules/pos/models/inventory')(app);
```

**In my routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    Inventory = require('./models/inventory')(app);
    app.get('/poss', function(req, res) {
        var result = Inventory.get();
        console.log('result1 is',result); // !
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
    });
}
```

**In my inventory.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    return {
        get : function() {
            var res;
            app.conn.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, rows) {
                res = JSON.stringify({users : rows});
                console.log("result is ",res); // !
                return res;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

P.S executing `node server` in the terminal, and browsing to localhost:8000 gives

`result1 is undefined`

`result is {"users":[{"id":1, "username": ...blah..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first console.log is executed before the second. And the `get` method doesn't return anything because the method that returns is the one inside the `get`. In order to make your method `async` add a callback, like this:

```
// inventory.js
module.exports = function(app) {
  return {
    get : function(cb) {
      app.conn.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, rows){
        if (err) {
          return cb(err);
        }
        res = JSON.stringify({users : rows}); 
        console.log("result is ", res);  
        cb(null, res)
      });
    } 
  };
};

// routes.js
module.exports = function(app) {

  var Inventory = require('./models/inventory')(app);

  app.get('/poss', function(req, res) {

    Inventory.get(function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        // do something else in case of error
        return;
      }
      res.end(result); // you don't need to use json stringify here cause the result is serialized
    });
  });

}
```